# Есть ли пути повышения производительности JavaScript-приложения, имеющегго связь с CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, графика, 3d

Я  написал  приложение, которое рисует композицию из кубов с разукрашенными гранями, которые висят в трёхмерном пространстве. Так же есть возмоожность управлять движением этой композиции в шести направлениях учитывая трёхмерную перспективу. При этом как бы чувствуешь себя летящим на корабле в трёхмерном пространстве между кубами.
Проблема в том, что во время такого полёта, когда кубы слишком близко, картинка не успевает сменяться с установленным периодом 100 мс, бывает,что даже секунды не хватает. Плюс, при этом греется процессор или может появиться сообщение, что не хватает оперативной памяти.
Хочу спросить, существуют ли какие-то программные приёмы, которые помогли бы решить эту проблему?

```css
*{
  margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
  perspective-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
body{ 
    perspective: 100vh; 
}
#mycontayner{
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
}
#contayner{
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left: 500px;
    width:500;
    height:300px;
}
.alldiv{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.mydiv {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/Rk0Grqv.gif');
}

.mydiv1 {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/a7FKzEo.gif');
}

.mydiv2 {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/Wbzg8nO.gif');
}
```

```html
<html><body>
<br />
Управление движениием:
<br /><br />
<button onclick="zap(1)"> влево </button>
<button onclick="zap(0)"> вправо </button>
<button onclick="zap(3)"> ввверх </button>
<button onclick="zap(2)"> вниз </button>
<button onclick="zap(5)"> вперёд </button>
<button onclick="zap(4)"> назад </button> | 
<button onclick="clearInterval(b)"> стоп </button>
<div id=mycontayner><div id=contayner></div></div>
<script>
var step = 60, stx = 0, sty = 0, stz = 0, tgx = true, tgy = true, tgz = true, stx1 = 15, sty1 = 15, b;
function promotion(){contayner.style.transform = "rotateX(-" + stx1 + "deg) rotateY(-" + sty1 + "deg) translateX(" + stx + "px) translateY(" + sty + "px) translateZ(" + stz + "px)"};
promotion();
function zap(e){
    clearInterval(b);
    b = setInterval(function(){
        promotion();
        switch(e){
            case 0: stx ++; break;
            case 1: stx --; break;
            case 2: sty ++; break;
            case 3: sty --; break;
            case 4: stz ++; break;
            case 5: stz --; break;
            case 8: stx1 ++; break;
            case 9: stx1 --; break;
            case 10: sty1 ++; break;
            case 11: sty1 --;
        }
    }, 100);
}
let x = 1; let y = 1; let z = 1;
for(l = 0; l < 5; l ++){
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
            if(Math.random() > 0.7){
                for(h = 0; h < 2; h ++){
                    let kv = document.createElement("div");
                    kv.classList.add("alldiv");
                    kv.classList.add("mydiv");
                    kv.style.transform = "rotateY(90deg) translateX(" + (l * step) + "px) translateZ(" + (h * 50 - 25) + "px)";
                    kv.style.left = (i * step) + "px";
                    kv.style.top = (j * step) + "px";
                    contayner.appendChild(kv);
                }
                for(h = 0; h < 2; h ++){
                    let kv = document.createElement("div");
                    kv.classList.add("alldiv");
                    kv.classList.add("mydiv1");
                    kv.style.transform = "translateZ(-" + (h * 50 - 25 + l * step) + "px)";
                    kv.style.left = (i * step) + "px";
                    kv.style.top = (j * step) + "px";
                    contayner.appendChild(kv);
                }
                for(h = 0; h < 2; h ++){
                    let kv = document.createElement("div");
                    kv.classList.add("alldiv");
                    kv.classList.add("mydiv2");
                    kv.style.transform = "rotateX(90deg) translateY(" + -l * step + "px) translateZ(" + (h * 50 - 25) + "px)";
                    kv.style.left = (i * step) + "px";
                    kv.style.top = (j * step) + "px";
                    contayner.appendChild(kv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Посмотреть в действии можно [тут](http://tolmatux.strana.de/pattern/mypattern.html)

[image: кубы]

Comment: Оказывается, на смартфоне нет перспективы.

Comment: Скорее всего, это из-за того, что у вас 228 блоков с анимированными гифками.

Comment: Есть перспектива или нет - зависит не от устройства, а от браузера.https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_perspective-origin

Comment: Действительно, если тыкнуть "назад" и ждать, по мере приближения постепенно начинает жрать до 100% CPU... Если в инструментах разработчика (`CTRL + SHIFT + I`) тыкнуть `performance` и записать 10 секундный промежуток, когда кубики далеко, и близко, можно убедиться, что в одном случае на `Recalculate Style` уходит по 20 мс, а после приближения 150+мс. Поиск в гугле "too long style recalculate" не дает ничего внятного кроме как "используйте меньше стилей". При таком количестве трансформаций оно и должно лагать. Попробовал бы разбить гифку на картинки и анимировать их из JS. Не уверен в успехе.

Comment: Я тоже. В JS-коде уже 3 вложенных цикла друг в друге, появится ещё четвёртый, имитирующий гиф-анимацию. Лучше не станет. До того, как были задействованы анимированныее гифки, были статические. Разницы в производительности никакой. Такое ощущение, что гиф-анимация тянет ресурсы вовсе не из браузера, а от куда-то из системы.